# Get information of a user who scans a QR code

Tags: android, ios, web-applications, qr-code, scanning

Is it possible, if someone scans a QR code that I made (or modify), that I get that person's phone number or other information?

For example, someone scanned a code from some flier and after a scan, I receive that person's phone number.

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible.  QR codes are just a way of encoding text or data, so it's just like if they read a URL off of the flier.

You can only tell if they actually engage with whatever was in the QR code: visit the link, call the phone number, connect to the Wi-Fi network, etc.